# How to make Angular Async Await work or wait till the http call is completed?

Tags: angular

Im having some issues with waiting to get a response. Here is the code
Component.ts on click of search button doSearch() will be called which then fires an http call to get data from a JSON.

```
doSearch() {
    console.log('reached 1');
    this.getDataFromJson();
    console.log('reached 5');
} 

getDataFromJson(): void {
    this.dataService.getdata().then((data: any) => {
      console.log('reached 3');
      data.forEach(item => {
        //console.log(item[1]);
      });
      console.log('reached 4');
    });
 }
```

DataService.ts:

Here the actual http call is made to fetch the json. 
Te json is in the assets/json folder.

```
datatURL = 'assets/json/data.json';    
async getdata() : Promise<MyData[]> {
    const result= await this.httpClient.get<MyData[]>(this.dataURL).toPromise();
    console.log('reached 2');
    return result;
}
```

I'm expecting the console to be printed as

- reached 1
- reached 2
- reached 3
- reached 4
- reached 5

but instead, the execution order is ( the http call is async with not wait ??)

- reached 1
- reached 5
- reached 2
- reached 3
- reached 4

I need to parse the data to get some information before the next block gets executed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Thank you. it solved my issue.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. You are referencing `this` and such, which means that you are likely in a class. Can you please provide your entire code?